# Spring boot @Qualifier doesn't work with datasources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, datasource

I'm building JPA configuration with multiple *persistence units* using different in-memory *datasources*, but the configuration fails resolving the qualified *datasource* for *entity manager factory bean* with the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method emfb in datasources.Application$PersistenceConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
        - ds1: defined by method 'ds1' in class path resource [datasources/Application$PersistenceConfiguration.class]
        - ds2: defined by method 'ds2' in class path resource [datasources/Application$PersistenceConfiguration.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

Here is the sample application

```
package datasources;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.JtaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
//      HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
//      DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class
        JtaAutoConfiguration.class
})
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
            .build()
            .run(args);
    }

    @Component
    @Path("/ds")
    public static class DsApi {

        private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DsApi.class);

        @Autowired(required = false)
        @Qualifier("ds1")
        private DataSource ds;

        @GET
        public String ds() {
            logger.info("ds");
            return ds.toString();
        }
    }

    @Component
    @Path("/em")
    public static class EmApi {

        private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EmApi.class);

        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ds2", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
        private EntityManager em;

        @GET
        public String em() {
            logger.info("em");
            return em.toString();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @ApplicationPath("/jersey")
    public static class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
        public JerseyConfig() {
            register(DsApi.class);
            register(EmApi.class);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class PersistenceConfiguration {

        @Bean
        @Qualifier("ds1")
        public DataSource ds1() {
            return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().build();
        }

        @Bean
        @Qualifier("ds2")
        public DataSource ds2() {
            return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().build();
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        @Autowired
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb(@Qualifier("ds1") DataSource ds, EntityManagerFactoryBuilder emfb) {
            return emfb.dataSource(ds)
                    .packages(Application.class)
                    .persistenceUnit("ds1")
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        @Autowired
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb2(@Qualifier("ds2") DataSource ds, EntityManagerFactoryBuilder emfb) {
            return emfb.dataSource(ds)
                    .packages(Application.class)
                    .persistenceUnit("ds2")
                    .build();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe its not working in a static class?

Comment: Couldn't be, as I tried to replace those DataSource beans with arbitrary type, and dependencies were resolved correctly. Also tried to return manually instantiated DataSource (No builder) with same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare one of your `DataSource` as `@Primary`.

Also you have 2 beans of same type - `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`, declare one of them `@Primary` as well, as follows:

```
@Configuration
public static class PersistenceConfiguration {

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DataSource ds1() {
            return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().build();
        }

        @Bean
        public DataSource ds2() {
            return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().build();
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        @Autowired
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb(@Qualifier("ds1") DataSource ds, EntityManagerFactoryBuilder emfb) {
            return emfb.dataSource(ds)
                    .packages(DemoApplication.class)
                    .persistenceUnit("ds1")
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        @Autowired
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb2(@Qualifier("ds2") DataSource ds, EntityManagerFactoryBuilder emfb) {
            return emfb.dataSource(ds)
                    .packages(DemoApplication.class)
                    .persistenceUnit("ds2")
                    .build();
        }
 }
```

Comment: This will inject ds1 to emfb2, which needs ds2

Comment: It should not as we are specifying the `@Qualifier("ds2")` while creating  `emfb2`

Comment: Indeed, you are right! But why Qualifier requires Primary to work? Also, why the same wiring worked fine without Primary, if those ds methods returned some other type instead (And of course emfb methods refactored to consume that type)?

Comment: Hope this help - http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html

Comment: Could you please add the import statement(s)?

Answer (score 4):

The error is indicating that at some point in the application, a bean is being injected by the type `DataSource` and not being qualified by name **at that point**.

It does not matter that you have added `@Qualifier` in one location. The injection is failing in some *other* location that has not been qualified. It's not your fault though because that location is in Spring Boot's `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` which you should be able to see in your stack trace, below the piece that you have posted.

I would recommend excluding `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` i.e. `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)`. Otherwise, this configuration is only being applied to the bean you have made `@Primary`. Unless you know exactly what that is, it is likely to result in subtle and unexpected differences in behaviour between your `DataSource`s.

Answer (score -1):

Try declaring the datasource beans outside the static class . I.e directly in Application.java